# Implementing Data Acess API using dependency Injection

Tags: java, web-services, api, dependency-injection, guice

I am new to writing API's and did some research and realize to accomplish what I want I would need to do it using Dependency Injection. I am writing an android application that haves two data source. One is expose by web services and the other is SQLlite. The SQLlite is used as backup when no data connection is available (Only interested for the webservice portion of the API for the time being will refactor). I want to write a API that provides a layer of abstraction to this that calls the right data access class based on the model required. Therefore, I have a interface that describes methods that the api should implement, called IDataAccess (Only interested in getAll for the purpose of figuring out what to do).

```
public interface IDataAccess {  
    public <T> List <T> getAll ();  
    public <T> T getById (int id);
}//end  IDataAccess
```

I am using Guice for dependency injection. The guice module is:

```
public class Data extends AbstractModule {
    public void configure () {
        bind (IDataAccess.class).to(UserData.class);
    }
}
```

and a Implementation of IDataAccess is (Note I am using Jersey Client API):

```
public class UserData extends DataAccessManager implements IDataAccess {    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List <User> getAll () {
        WebResource webResource = client.resource (WebResourceURL.URL_USER_ALL);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (response.getStatus () == 200)
            return response.getEntity(new GenericType <List <User>> () {}) ;
        else
            return null;        
    }//end getAllUsers method
}
```

I have a class that loads and instantiates any resource needed. It also returns a instance of a DataManager called DataAccessFactory.

```
public class DataAccessFactory {
    private Client client;
    private static DataAccessFactory instance;
    private DataAccessFactory() {
        client = Client.create();
    }
    public static DataAccessFactory getInstance() {
        /*
         * check if instance  variable is instantiated.
         * if it is not then instantiated it and returns
         * created instance.
         */
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DataAccessFactory();
            return instance;
        } else
            return instance;
    }//end getInstance method
    public DataAccessManager createDataAccessManager() {
        return new DataAccessManager(client);
    }//end createDataAccessManager method
}
```

Then I have the actual DataAccessManager class:

```
public class DataAccessManager {
    protected Client client;
    protected DataAccessManager (Client client)n{
        this.client = client;
    }//end constructor 
    public <T>  List <Object> getAll(T t) {
        Data module = new Data ();
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        IDataAccess data = (IDataAccess) injector.getInstance(t.getClass());
        return (List<Object>) data;
    }//end fetchAllUser method
}
```

To call the user model on this class I would do something like this:

```
@Test
public void fetchUser () {
        DataAccessManager m = DataAccessFactory.getInstance().createDataAccessManager();
        List<User> user = (List<User>)  m.getAll(new Userdata ());
        if (user == null)
            assertEquals(1, 2);
        else
            assertEquals(1, 1);
}
```

Ideally what I want this to do now is, call the UserData to get all the User objects or the OrderData (When implementation is written) class to get all the order objects etc.

The problem is that this is giving a error:

> Cannot cast from List to List

.How can I fix this problem or restructure this so that it makes sense?

Comment: Are you using Spring Framework or something else?  Or are you asking how to implement DI yourself?  I think the latter is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You are creating an injector (`Guice.createInjector`) per request. Injector creation is expensive and should normally be done during application loading. You should see DI as a bootstrap mechanism and keep it simple.

2) You don't need the DataAccessFactory. First there is no need for a factory as the createDataAccessManager instantiation does not require any logic and secondly Guice could also take care of the factory pattern.

I would personally keep it simple and inject with Guice directly the `UserData` instance into each service that needs it, without using the rather complicated Abstraction approach showed here. Still, it does not solve the problem of dealing with network issues. My guess is that each data access class will have to deal with connectivity in a specific way, so the logic should be directly here.

For the list casting problem, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

If you will continue that way, I would recommend to read about [erasure](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html&ei=tyqAUMiFLtDOsgb_mIHwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEBnOVe2r3hRwjUknNy696Du68q-Q&sig2=jXNXYSeR2RQlnOOoNhLJvA) also.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem you fall for. We'd expect that as `String` is-a `Object`, `List<String>` is-a `List<Object>` is true too. But it isn't. This is why this class cast won't work:

```
@Test
public void fetchUser () {
//...
List<User> user = (List<User>)  m.getAll(new Userdata ());
//..
}
```

I suggest to rewrite the `DataAccessManager.getAll()` method to return the right kind of list.

For the record, I found a typo in `DataAccessManager.getAll()` method. I think when you wrote `return (List<Object>) data;` then you rather wanted to write `return List<Object> data.getAll();` Otherwise you just cannot cast IDataAccess to List.

To escape from this casting hell I suggest to add a type to the `IDataAccess` interface and to its implementations:

```
public interface IDataAccess<T> {  
    public List <T> getAll ();  
    public T getById (int id);
}//end  IDataAccess

public class UserData extends DataAccessManager<User> implements IDataAccess<User> {
// your implementation
}
```

I'd also clarify DataAccesManager itself:

```
public class DataAccessManager<T> {
    //fields and constructors
    public List<T> getAll(IDataAccess<T> access) { //this is how the test suggests you want to use this method
        Data module = new Data ();
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        IDataAccess<T> data = (IDataAccess<T>) injector.getInstance(access.getClass()); //why is this line important? why don't you use the access parameter instead?
        return data.getAll();
    }
}
```